# If $x$ is any positive real number, then prove that there exists a non-negative integer denoted by $[x]$ such that $[x]\leq x<[x]+1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> **If $x$ is any positive real number, then prove that there exists a non-negative integer denoted by $[x]$ such that $[x]\leq x<[x]+1$**.
>
> (A Hints is given as: Apply Archimedean Property in $\mathbb{R}$)

I know the Archimedian property as:

If $a(>0), b\in \mathbb{R}$, then there exits at least one positive integer $n$, such that $na>b$.

here, how to choose $a,b, n$.? How to use the theory to prove the result.

Comment: Your "Archimidean property" is actually a corollary of the Archimidean property that for every real number $x$ there exists a natural number $n$ such that $n>x$

Comment: Don't you think this is the definition for the greatest integer function?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Yes. the definition is for the greatest integer function. But how to prove by Archimedean Property is a problem

Comment: @smcc Yes. I understand.  Applying Archimedean Property how to prove that.

Comment: This appears to be http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117734/proof-of-greatest-integer-theorem-floor-function-is-well-defined restricted to positive reals.

Answer (score 2):

AP $\implies$ there exist $n$ such that $n > x$. The set X = {$m: m>x$} is a non empty set of positive integers so it has a minimum element $k$. Then $[x] :=k-1$ (if $k -1 > x$ then $k-1$ is an element of $X$ but it can't be so $k-1 \le x$)

Comment: If $x$ is not an integer, would't it be $[x] = k-1$? We're supposed to have $[x]\leq x$, after all.

Comment: @Arthur right! see edit