# Let $x \in \mathbb R$. Prove that the $\lceil{x}\rceil$ is unique; that is, prove that there is at most one $n \in \mathbb Z$ with $n − 1 < x ≤ n.$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I recently had a discrete math midterm that I am trying to review, and one of the topics that really has me confused is the idea of proving uniqueness.

> Let $x \in \mathbb R$. Prove that the $\lceil{x}\rceil$ is unique; that is, prove that there is at most one $n \in \mathbb Z$ with $n − 1 < x ≤ n.$

My professor, when doing these problems in the past, tended to use $x'$ as a second variable when proving uniqueness, but I am struggling with comprehending the logic behind these proofs. I understand the structure, i.e. that you are trying to prove that $x, x'$ both make the predicate true and that implies that $x=x'$, but I can't execute any of these proofs.

Also, please note that I am not trying to prove the existence here, but instead uniqueness.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I saw that post, but that seemed as though it was trying to prove existence, not uniqueness, albeit on a similar problem. I could be reading the post incorrectly, but I posted this one because it seemed like a different problem to me.

Comment: Yeah, I can say after reviewing the linked post extensively that the questions are asking for different things. Where as proving existence involves proving that there is **at least** one x that makes the condition true, whereas uniqueness proves that there is **at most** one x that makes the condition true, and they have distinct proof structures.

Comment: You can see [proof-that-floor-function-is-well-defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117734/proof-of-greatest-integer-theorem-floor-function-is-well-defined).